# Handsontable multiple and parameterizable column validators

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I need multiple validation rules per column and parameters for the validators. For instance I might have a required decimal with 8 whole and 4 decimals. I would like to avoid defining all the possibilities but it looks like the validators only have the value parameter that I can use.

Comment: you can pass in multiple validators to a column, if that's what you were asking

Comment: @ZekeDroid Doesn't look like it. I tried doing validator: [validator1, validator2]. Doesn't work. How would I go about it?

Comment: you're right...I forgot I came up with a custom solution. What you want to do is pass in a generic validator function which iterates through each cell's list of validators, passing around callbacks since they're all asynch. I'll try and come up with an example